# How to get a reference to markers autogenerated by the creation of the symbol layer?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I need to perform automated actions on individual markers on my map, but based on all the answers I'm finding online I will first need to store references to my markers in my script. However, I am not creating the markers explicitly. Instead it seems the markers are being generated when I load a collection of points from geojson using the `map.addSource()` and `map.addLayer()` methods.

[For an MCVE see here.](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/)

How can I get references to the generated markers using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing [Markers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/) (HTML elements that sit above the map) with a [symbol layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol) (graphical elements that exist within the map). Symbol layers don't generate markers, and there are no "references" to get.

Comment: Hmm, okay... that *does* make sense looking at the code, but then it means that when mapbox makes a tutorial entitled "Add markers to a web map with a symbol layer", as linked in my original post, it's a misnomer made by mapbox themselves, as we are not in fact adding markers to the map.

Comment: Or, are you saying that a "marker" in mapbox lingo refers to 2 different things simultaneously?

Comment: Sorry to comment spam. My assumption at this point is that the symbol layer *does* technically create markers but they are inaccessible to me, so I must also create a duplicate set of markers manually and overlay them (invisibly) to do what I need to happen

Comment: The tutorial is using the word "marker" informally, as opposed to the actual `Marker` class which is completely different. Your assumption is wrong, but your conclusion is reasonable.

Comment: Actually I have no idea if your conclusion is reasonable, I don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you want to respond to mouse events, you can do that for symbols within a symbol layer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using React so I ended up using [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/), which made the creation of (the right kind of) markers outside of the symbol layer a lot simpler.